# android, sax parser duplication error

Tags: android, xml, listview, sax

I am trying to parse a moderately large xml file, store it in an ArrayList then display results in an listview. Currently I have got a problem, but cannot find a solution. Firstly here is my sax parser code:

```
     try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            boolean DayofWeek = false;
            boolean DateDD = false;             
            String dayofweek = null; 
            String datedd = null;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException  {
                System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DayofWeek"))  {
                    DayofWeek = true;
                }
                else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Date-DD"))  {
                    DateDD = true;
                }

                                   // ommited
            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,String qName) throws SAXException  {        

            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException  {
                if (DayofWeek) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch,start,length));
                    dayofweek =  new String(ch, start, length);
                    DayofWeek = false;
                }
                else if (DateDD) {
                    System.out.println(new String(ch,start,length));
                    datedd =  new String(ch, start, length);
                    DateDD = false;
                }
                // ommited
                else if (dayofweek != null) {
                    System.out.println("Do i reach here?");
                    addElement(dayofweek, datedd, datemm, dateyy, time, competition, home, away, venue); //is run
                }
            }
        };
        saxParser.parse(is, handler);

    }  catch (Exception e)  {
        System.out.println("Sax Error");
        Log.w("SaxError", e);
    }
}

private void addElement(String dayofweek, String datedd, String datemm, String dateyy, String time, String competition, String home, String away, String venue)  {
    System.out.println("Add Element");
    AddObjectToList(dayofweek, datedd);
}

// Add one item into the Array List
public void AddObjectToList(String dayofweek, String datedd, String datemm, String dateyy, String time, String competition, String home, String away, String venue) {
    System.out.println("AddObjectToList");
    fixture = new FixtureSupport();
    fixture.setDayOfWeek(dayofweek);
    fixture.setDateDD(datedd);
    itemList.add(fixture);
}
```

In logcat, this will print all the information correctly, but nothing will go into the AddElement document so nothing appears in the listview. Whereas, if I were to change all the 'else if' statements to 'if' statements the code will print out in the listview but each XML element will get repeated about 10 or so times (seems random). Whilst it also repeats itself it only prints one of the xml elements at a time and gradually other elements get added to it.

I can't understand why this is happening, any help please guys!

Thanks

Comment: replace else if (dayofweek != null) with  if (dayofweek != null)

Comment: That allows it to be displayed in the listview which is good, but the replication is still happening. :-(

Comment: This is happens because your list having duplicate values, so before passing List of items to adapter, remove duplicates.

Comment: When you say duplicate, duplicates in the XML file itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this issue:

```
        boolean DayofWeek = false;
        String dayofweek = null;
```

1) It's completely confusing

2) variables should always start with a lower case letter

3) I have no clue if this affects your code logic

Try:

```
        boolean foundDayofWeek = false;
        String dayOfWeekText = null;
```

Ref: [Java Naming Conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)

Your characters() method needs to append to a StringBuffer, not all characters may be sent at once, so you have to keep appending then in the endElement() method you call .toString on your buffer.

```
  // Pseudo
  Stringbuffer yourStringBuffer;

  startElement() {
    yourStringBuffer = new Stringbuffer();
  }

  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
      yourStringBuffer.append(ch, start, start + length);
  }

  endElement() {
      // If ....
      String elementText = yourStringBuffer.toString();
  }
```

Ref: [OTT XML Parsing](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/26/xml.html?page=2)

Methods should also start with a lowercase letter just for clarity (Class names are uppercase) change:

```
 AddObjectToList()
```

to

```
 addObjectToList();
```

and see how we go from there.

Comment: Thanks, currently making some changes! :)

Comment: http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html Is a nice Android article, although it suffers from the characters() issue

Comment: Ok, I have done the changes and the same issue is still there. The XML has 9 elements I need in total. Will I need 1 or 9 StringBuffers?

Comment: 1 so in the endElement you set it to whatever you where doing in char, and in startElement you reinstantiate it i.e. new StringBuffer(); This then moves your addElement() call into endElement() which makes more sense :-)

Comment: String Buffers seems to not make a difference !

Comment: Yes but your code is clearer :) ok now in your endElement method you need to work out when you have a full FixtureSupport object and call itemList.add.

Comment: Next time I see you in the pub I'll be claiming that :-)